# Braintree drop-in UI (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, braintree

I am trying to customize the appearance of the Braintree drop-in VC:

[image: BT drop-in UI]

E.g. apply clear background color or background image to the whole thing. I can't seem to nail it. For instance, there's no backgroundView property to set an image to since it's a static UITableView.

Also, I can see there's support for themes..?

Has anyone successfully managed to customise the drop-in on top of the basic things that you can do as per [Braintree's guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v3)?

Comment: From previous projects with Braintree integrations, you can either 1. Use their drop in UI or 2. Make a custom interface. I opted for the custom option, I am pretty sure you can't actual manipulate their drop in view at all.

Comment: I was able to change some stuff on the drop-in but nothing crazy. I am specifically interested to find out more on their "theme" support.

Comment: Hi Polis, can you maybe share snippet of code that shows how you changed callToAction button color or any other color? I tried subclassing BTUI, assigning it to dropInControoler.theme and overriding methods to return new color values but that is not working.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

Theming for the Drop-in integration is not publicly supported at this time. However, this is an open source project and you can modify the Drop-in to fit your needs.

Comment: thx! I managed to change background views and colors by accessing the properties of each element (i.e. layer of PayButton, etc), and I am OK with the results. However, I get the weirdest behaviour when I add a picture in the navigationBar of your dropIn; it initially appears black (clear) for about 10 seconds and then the picture is shown. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hi, full disclosure: I also work at Braintree. Can you try adding a picture into a navigation bar of a custom view controller that you've created? This will help us diagnose whether it's an iOS/network issue or a Braintree issue.

Comment: Sorry @RichardShin I can't send a screenshot because I ended up removing the picture from the navigationBar due to this behaviour.

Comment: @KathrynExline you answer is outdated and no longer valid, correct? https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/ios/v4

Answer (score 0):

Themes are now supported in Braintree iOS v4 SDK:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/ios/v4